# Google Map v3 API KML overlay no longer loads kml files

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm not sure why this suddenly began happening, but my application that uses the google maps api and jquery no longer loads the KML files as it once did.  There have been no code changes on my part so I don't know what the cause could be.  I've updated the jquery libraries thinking that may have caused the issue with no luck.  I've made sure the kml files still exist in the correct location which they do.  I've read that google is changing how KML overlays will work but my understanding of the article is that would be in February however I'm not counting that out yet.

If I was to guess, I would say it's the setMap() function no longer supported but at this point I have no idea, I'm just guessing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Below is the code i use to load the KML files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuerythemes/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuerythemes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuerythemes/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css" />       

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuerythemes/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQuerythemes/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="jQuerythemes/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageshow', '#map_page', function () {
        initialize();
        layersOFFonload();          
    });

var routesLayerKML = [];

function initialize() {
        // set the default center of the map
        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(55.1669513, -118.8031093);

        //updateMapSize(mapCenter);
        // set the display options for the map
        var myOptions = {
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: mapCenter
        }
        // add the map to the map placeholder
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        });

 var kmlOptions = {
            suppressInfoWindows: false,
            preserveViewport: false,
            map: map
        };

 routesLayerKML[0] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://mydomain/KML/mobile_route1.kml', kmlOptions);
        routesLayerKML[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://mydomain/KML/mobile_route2.kml', kmlOptions);
        routesLayerKML[2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://mydomain/KML/mobile_route3.kml', kmlOptions);

function layersOFFonload(){
        routesLayerKML[0].setMap(null);
        routesLayerKML[1].setMap(null);
        routesLayerKML[2].setMap(null);           
               } 

    function toggleLayer(i) {   
        if (routesLayerKML[i].getMap() === null) {
            routesLayerKML[i].setMap(map);
        }
        else {
            routesLayerKML[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }


<div data-role="page" id="map_page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="routeLayersPage" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Routes</h1>
        </div>        
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="routesLayerKML0" onclick="toggleLayer(0)" />
                <label for="routesLayerKML0">Route 1</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="routesLayerKML1" onclick="toggleLayer(1)" />
                <label for="routesLayerKML1">Route 2</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="routesLayerKML2"  onclick="toggleLayer(2)" />
                <label for="routesLayerKML2">Route 3</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="routesLayerKML3" onclick="toggleLayer(3)" />
            </div>
            <a href="#my-header" data-role="button" data-rel="close">Close panel</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: [KmlLayer works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/SO_ab9Plan0520.kmz).  Perhaps your server configuration changed and is no longer serving those files with the correct MIME type (that happened to me).  Can't tell that without a link to the KML.

Comment: Your absolutely correct!!   That was the exact issue, I'm not sure why or when that would have changed but yet the MIME type was missing completely.  Thanks for the response.

Sure would be great to know why someone voted down my reputation for that post.  That is the issue with this forum, people like that preventing others from gaining enough reputation points to actually post answers for others.  Before you click that down button you should have to post a reason.  pfff.

Comment: Check with your hosting company.  When it happened to me it was because someone had hacked my site and there was an exploit active.

Answer (score 0):

As @geocodezip stated, the MIME type was missing from IIS.